# Domain an Heroku DNS

Tags: heroku, dns

I've bought a domain www.myapp.com and created an app on Heroku myapp.herokuapp.com . 
I want to delegate my domain to my heroku app.

1.I've added the domain to Settings-> Domains in Heroku. The myapp0123.herokudns.com DNS was created.

2.I've assigned the DNS to my domain on my provider's deashboard.

The domein still doesn't point to the app.
When I type www.myapp.com I receive "This site can’t be reached", error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you share the real domain name?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't.